# How can I make voronoi treemaps?

Tags: statistics, voronoi, treemaps

I want to make voronoi treemaps for statistics data, like
[image]
[newsgraphy](http://newsgraphy.com/)

Do you know how I can do that in Perl, PHP, Ruby, or Python?

Comment: curious example picture.  I don't think there's any set of points that gives this as a Voronoi tessellation.  in particular the two long straight lines make me suspicious.

Comment: It could be, if hierarchical order were allowed (i.e., tesellations of lower levels inside each cell).

The tree would then need to have a first level consisting of two elements (the vertical bar would appear if the two points shared equal height); the second and last level would hold the points of the cells shown at each side of the vertical line. Incidentally, this image is the first result when googling "Voronoi treemaps"; see http://www-hagen.informatik.uni-kl.de/~kerren/courses/lecture/ws06/infovis/papers/VoronoiTreemapInfoVis2005.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice demos and graphics for Python: http://home.scarlet.be/zoetrope/voronoi/ ([Archived copy at wayback](http://web.archive.org/web/20100110083040/http://home.scarlet.be/zoetrope/voronoi/))

Answer (score 6):

[Math::Geometry::Voronoi](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Math::Geometry::Voronoi)

Answer (score 2):

Just found this page. I've been working on a Voronoi demo applet using Javascript/canvas, after translating into Javascript a C# version of Steven Fortune's algorithm by Benjamin Dittes (available at Code Project, see "Fortune's Voronoi algorithm implemented in C#"). Here is the page which include Fortune's Voronoi algorithm in Javascript:
http://www.raymondhill.net/voronoi/voronoi.php
This is a first iteration, I plan to adapt it further to be better suited to Javascript. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

the other Python answer seems to point at a **raster only** solution.  I am also interested in solving this problem (in Python) and I think the following script could form a usable starting point:

http://www.oxfish.com/python/voronoi.py

([Archived copy at wayback](http://web.archive.org/web/20100531065334/http://www.oxfish.com/python/voronoi.py))

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the lines are not strange: it's the result of the fact that this is not a normal Voronoi tessellation, but an area-weighted Voronoi (AWT) tessellation, possibly even a centroidal Voronoi tessellation (CVT). That being said, in order to have Voronoi regions (polygons) with significantly differing areas (which would reflect some attribute of the data), you need AWTs (preferably implemented as CVTs to retain nice aspect ratios for the polygons); a normal Voronoi algorithm (as suggested by some people above) will not be able to help you. There is probably no direct solution for this available, especially not for scripted languages, since the computational complexity due to iterative updating steps for AWTs is quite high. You should look up the work on "Voronoi Treemaps" and "Dynamic Voronoi Treemaps" by Balzer et al. and Sud et al. to get an idea of the algorithm and then implement it on your own (everything that you need is in their papers).

Answer (score 1):

James Tauber is writing a tutorial that uses JavaScript and [Fortune's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune%27s_algorithm) to draw a Voronoi diagram in a `canvas` element: [Voronoi Canvas Tutorial](http://jtauber.com/blog/2008/11/27/voronoi_canvas_tutorial_part_i/)

It's not complete yet (he's at part 3 of 4) but there's enough there to complete it I think.

Comment: tanks!!. but I want to draw bounded voronoi ; 
and treemaps ...

Answer (score 1):

The latest version (2.0) of [Macrofocus TreeMap](http://www.treemap.com/) has the Voronoi algorithm as an option, among others.