# Visualize data with heatmap like a cell

Tags: visualization, data-visualization, diagram, heatmap, treemap

I'm looking for an algorithm or method, that can visualize/create nice diagram from data. The data has size and quality properties (and there are some categorys). I found out that treemaps/heatmaps are good for that. But I need an extreme solution. Something like a cell.
I have a good example:
https://www.destatis.de/Voronoi/PriceKaleidoscope.svg

Is it possible to generate diagrams like that (with changing data)? Is there an algorithm for that? Where should I look for more information? Is there a program that does something similar to that?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called a vornonoi treemap. Check out the links on this other [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838265/how-can-i-make-voronoi-treemaps) and this [paper from SoftVis 2005](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/1056018.1056041).

Answer (score 0):

You can make that kind of map via **d3.js** http://d3js.org/ ,and there is a treemap example  http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/treemap.html .